# Does PHP offer file concurrency in this scenario?

Tags: php, apache, unix, centos

I have a cache file that is updated every hour or so. The file size ranges from 100KB to 1MB. The way the cache is updated is with the file_put_contents() method.

**Only** the server writes to the file. However, there is continuous access to the file. The file is accessed by users by a script that performs a one time read through readfile() to echo it to the user.

If the file is being read by the caching script, and the server runs the user reading script, or the other way around, would there be a problem? Or is this handled automatically by PHP>

Comment: Yes, It would be some problems.

Comment: there is no point to say if yes or no without knowing how php is invoked in your server mod cgi etc and how your php.config is set ... probable there are no problems if everything is configuered right :D

Comment: What sort of things should I look for in the php configuration files? Also I think I have php.ini, or is that a different one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you should lock the file while writing or reading. At least, it guarantees that there is no problem. It is the way of good programming!. The example is shown below.

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "w+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { // do an exclusive lock
    fwrite($fp, "Write something here\n");
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't lock the file !";
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

[More information](http://www.php.net/flock)

Comment: What happens when the file is being read with readfile but it's locked? Or should I check if it's locked before attempting to read? And in that case, should I sleep for a certain time and then try to read again?

Comment: Note that you should check before you attempt to read the file. The flock() function locks or releases a file. This function returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.